# Opencart Unable to edit orders from admin end

Tags: php, opencart

Unable to edit orders in Version 2.0.2.0. It shows 'Payment method required!' warning when I try to save changes. API is starting perfectly. I've gone through other related posts but no use.

Comment: This question is likely better suited for the Opencart support forums.. https://forum.opencart.com/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will post there as well.